# Random failure with casperjs fill & select box

Tags: javascript, html-select, casperjs

Once in ten, my country select box does not update my value, it let the default value which is another country.

I dont know why.

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.fill('.my-form-class', {
    address: '17 rue dulong'
    city: 'Paris'
    country: 'France'
  }, true);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using xpath's.  you need to inject the xpath heading at the top of your casper script before doing this.

```
casper.sendKeys(x('yourXPath', 'keys to send'));
```

If this is not a good solution you could always inject jQuery into your script and just use jQuery to change the value of your element.

Comment: Thanks I will try with xpath's.

Comment: In this video I show how to fill out a form using xpath's. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kefil5tCL9o

Comment: I cant fill select box with sendKeys but I can with fillXpath. I hope to not have random result. I try this morning. I will tell you my results

Comment: It's not possible because sendKeys works only with "input" and "textarea" element, not "select" list like I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems before.  In my situation, occurred when there was form validation on a field.

Try this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    if (casper.exists('.my-form-class')) {
        this.fill('.my-form-class', {
           address: '17 rue dulong',
           city: 'Paris',
           country: 'France'
        }, false);

        this.click('button[type="submit"][name="__HERE__"]'); // Can use ID or name here
    }
});
```

[Casper Button Click Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click)